Hand Railing Reinforcement Needed
We have a wood railing up our staircase that has had a few joints loosen (see pic). I sadly attempted to fill with wood filler but that just recracked with touch.  What is the best way to tighten the joint and connect to the wall?

handrail
(Please don’t hate on my lack of craftsmanship here as I am just starting out.  Thank you!)

wood screws into the joint to bring it together

How are those two pieces fastened together?

I didn’t take it apart to see so maybe that is the best to take the rail off and check..  looks like some sort of dowel or screw.
